# How can I build a bed frame out of palettes?

Tags: wood, bedroom

I'm moving to a new house, and on a broke budget. I found [this bed design](http://m.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/spr/29023237/) online.

I'd like to do this from scratch and perhaps use wooden palettes for the main structure (adding supplemental wood for the legs, seams, etc.). Any ideas on how to really do that? Sorry for the vagueness, this is completely out of my territory.

Answer (score 4):

Believe it or not, there is an entire Pinterest page dedicated to beds made out of pallets. There are no instructions, but plenty of designs in addition to your IKEA model that you can use for inspiration. Some involve simply stacking the pallets in various configurations, but several of them are quite stylish and it's pretty easy to see how they disassembled some pallets and screwed them back together to make a nice frame.

Have a look!

[Pallet Beds](http://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=pallet%20bed)

Comment: That was pretty cool, a lot of variations on a theme to choose from.

Comment: Don't count on easy disassembly... most pallets are constructed with distorted-shank (usually twisted-shank) nails, and are nearly impossible to get apart except by cutting (with a cheap nasty "nail finder" sawblade). They CAN be hand-sawn apart, though. Sometimes you even get lucky and find exotic hardwoods in a pallet...